# Bind date and time in asp.net core mvc view

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can't Bind datetime to  in view

this is the model

```
public class ListaDisponibiliModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:f}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DataOraInizio { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}")]
    public DateTime DataOraFine { get; set; }
}
```

I call the view by controller with this code

```
public IActionResult ListDisponibili()
{
    ListaDisponibiliModel ldm = new ListaDisponibiliModel() 
    { 
        DataOraInizio = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), 
        DataOraFine = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).AddHours(3), 
        Tipologie = es.Tipologie, 
        Disponibili = new List<DisponibiliModel>() 
    };
    return View(ldm);
}
```

in view i've got this markup

```
@model ServiziAPagamento.Models.Disponibilita.ListaDisponibiliModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ListDisponibili";
}

<h1>Composizione servizi</h1>

<h3>Dati servizio</h3>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form asp-action="ListDisponibili">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Data e ora inizio</label>
                    <input class="form-control" asp-for="DataOraInizio" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Data e ora fine</label>
                    <input class="form-control" asp-for="DataOraFine" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

when i run the page my input box remain clear. But if I remove

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:f}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

or

```
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}")]
```

my input box show date time and also seconds millisecond that I don't want.

can someone help me?

Comment: What happens if you just use: `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]`?

Comment: @mxmissile If I do what you have suggest my input box show date time but it show also second and milliseconds

Comment: There is an open issue regarding to that: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10992. For now I guess the workaround is to put the dates as text inputs, and use jQuery datetimepicker to format those.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [Tempus Dominus](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/) (bootstrap-datetimepicker).

```
@model ListaDisponibiliModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ListDisponibili";
}

<h1>Composizione servizi</h1>

<h3>Dati servizio</h3>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form asp-action="ListDisponibili">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Data e ora inizio</label>
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                        <input class="form-control datetimepicker-input" asp-for="DataOraInizio" type="text" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
                        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Data e ora fine</label>
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-target-input="nearest">
                        <input class="form-control datetimepicker-input" asp-for="DataOraFine" type="text" data-target="#datetimepicker2" />
                        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>


@section Scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
    <script>

        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
        });

        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class ListaDisponibiliModel
{

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}")]
    public DateTime DataOraInizio { get; set; }

    
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}")]
    public DateTime DataOraFine { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]